# Regex find and replace (c# .net)

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a long HTML page as a string.  Throughout, I have image tags with text like this:

```
cid:@(Model.MyImage)
```

I have strings storing the path and file extension.  I'd like to replace the above to get

```
[mypath]MyImage.[myExtension]
```

So I'd like to capture that MyImage text and use it in my new string - then get rid of all the cid: stuff and put the standard path in.

So, cid:@(Model.MainChart) might become C:\MainChart.png

**EDIT**

Per the answer below, the question has been answered nicely.  Example of usage below:

```
string first = @"<img src=""cid:@(Model.FirstOne)"" style=""max-width:600px;"" then <img src=""cid:@(Model.Another)"" style=""max-width:600px;"")";
            string pathPrefix = @"C:\";
            string extension = ".png";
            string newPath = Regex.Replace(first, @"cid:@\(Model\.([^)]*)\)", pathPrefix + "$1" + extension);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you. The Regex is:

```
cid:@\(Model\.([^)]*)\)
```

and the replacement string should contain a `$1` for the found image.

Comment: What did you mean by "and the replacement string should contain a $1 for the found image." ?

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks Fischermaen.  I'll post the worked solution in the question.